# use sum function of groovy-ginq ,but the result is error

Tags: groovy

```
public static final String groovyScript= """
            GQ { from o in tuple select sum(o.A) }
            """;

    HashMap<String,Double> a = new HashMap<>();
    a.put("A",1.6);
    HashMap<String,Double> b = new HashMap<>();
    b.put("A",1.8);
    tuple.add(a);
    tuple.add(b);

    GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell();
    groovyShell.setVariable("tuple", tuple);
    Object result = groovyShell.evaluate(groovyScript);
```

the result is 3.2 , not 3.4 ,why? how to fix? thank you

I changed `HashMap<String,Double>` to `HashMap<String,BigDecimal>`, but it did not work.

Comment: b.put("B", 1.8); not b.put("A", 1.8);

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel no

Comment: Also min/max/... only use the first value. workaround: `from a in (from o in tuple select o.A) select sum(a)`; feels like a bug to me.

Comment: @cfrick `from a in (from o in tuple select o.A) select sum(a)`  .it works.

Comment: @cfrick  `a.put("a",1.6);`  `from o in tuple select o.a` it also work . the bug is due to capital letter.